# go-mail embed image not working with exe

Tags: go, gomail

I am using go-mail to send mail.
I am embedded image in to mail
by
m.Embed("common/static/img/logo.png")
and use this in HTML by

It works fine when running main.go. But when I bould project and execute main.exe I am  getting error "The system can not found path specified."

Comment: What directory are you in when you run the executable? It is looking for the image relative to wherever you are.

Comment: use this https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata

Comment: I copied executable from work space to desktop and tried to run it. should i need to copy static files as well? Is it possible to package static file in executable?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple problems here.

One is that the file path you've used has platform-specific path separators. Windows uses "\" instead of "/". To write platform-agnostic paths use https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Join

```
filepath.Join("common", "static", "img", "logo.png")
```

The other problem, as Yandry Pozo pointed out, is that you might not have packaged up the logo.png file and distributed it with your code. If that is the case, than something like https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata might help.